# How to store this values

Tags: java, programming-languages, solr, types

is there type is there to store the value

```
     <string,string,int>
```

if i use Namedlist(Solr),List it can be achieved? if so how to use.

Any other way is there?

example:

```
   <"A",America,code>
   <"B",London,code>
```

I need this in java

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: No, but you could write it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you create a Class compose of these datatypes.

Example:

```
class MyObject
{
    int code;
    String country;
    String Flag;

    // Getters and Setters goes here.
}
```

Now we can use this class in a List.

```
List<MyObject> list;
```

Comment: Even better - provide a constructor that sets the datatypes (instead of setters) and make them `final`.  There's almost zero reasons to make a small object like this mutable.

Comment: can you say how to do that.. sorry .. i am new to do this.. pls provide a sample example... Thanks for all

Comment: `class MyObject
{
    final int code;
    final String country;
    final String Flag;
    public MyObject(int code, String country, String flag){
        this.code = code;
        this.country = country;
        this.Flag = flag;
    }
}`

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Triple<T1, T2, T3> {

 private T1 o1;
 private T2 o2; 
 private T3 o3;

 public Triple(T1 o1, T2 o2, T3 o3) {
  this.o1 = o1;
  this.o2 = o2;
  this.o3 = o3;
 }

 public void setO1(T1 o1) {
  this.o1 = o1;
 }
 public T1 getO1() {
  return o1;
 }
 public void setO2(T2 o2) {
  this.o2 = o2;
 }
 public T2 getO2() {
  return o2;
 }
 public void setO3(T3 o3) {
  this.o3 = o3;
 }
 public T3 getO3() {
  return o3;
 }
}
```

Example:

```
List<Triple<String, Integer, String>> list 
  = new ArrayList<Triple<String, Integer, String>>();
list.add(new Triple("tr1", 1, "Triple 1"));
list.add(new Triple("tr2", 2, "Triple 2"));
list.add(new Triple("tr3", 3, "Triple 3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it depends on how you will use it. For example, if you will always look for code when you have country+flag (and vice versa), it makes sence to group county+flag:

```
  Map<Map<String,String>,Integer> myMap...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Location> map = new HashMap<String, Location>();

        map.put("B", City.London);
    }
}

enum City implements Location {
    London(262);
    private int code;

    private City(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
}

interface Location {
     int getCode();
}
```

This allows to search by primary key. And makes constant like code linked to location constant. Covering interface will allow to put there different enum constants/objects.

Comment: Why do you `@Override` the getCode(), it's only a implementation of an interface?

Comment: If someone removes this method from interface I will get compilation error and consider removing it from my implemetation.